# Rename [cocoa] to [cocoa-osx]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Could the [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) tag be renamed to [cocoa-osx](/questions/tagged/cocoa-osx)? Cocoa on Mac OS X is not the same as Cocoa on iOS and, even though there’s a [cocoa-touch](/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) tag, every day I end up retagging Cocoa Touch questions that have been tagged [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa).

Although the term Cocoa is used in some circles for both Cocoa on Mac OS X and Cocoa on iOS, they are different frameworks:

- [Apple themselves make a distinction between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html);
- Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are not the same. Various classes in Cocoa are not available in Cocoa Touch and vice versa. Even when a class is available in both Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, its methods can be restricted to only one of the frameworks;
- iOS is more restrictive with regard to what applications can do. A Cocoa for Mac OS X solution doesn’t necessarily apply to iOS;
- If we [consider Cocoa as meaning the whole SDK available to a given platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63869/iphone-sdk-as-synomym-of-cocoa-touch-instead-of-iphone/63899#63899), the differences between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch are even greater.

I believe the main drawback in renaming [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) to [cocoa-osx](/questions/tagged/cocoa-osx) would be old questions. I’ve been policing [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) for a while but I’m not sure whether it’s worth it to retag those old questions.

Comment: Why not tag them with `[cocoa]` in combination with the appropriate OS?

Comment: I agree with the goal of reducing mistagged “[tag:cocoa]” questions (particularly as I subscribe to [tag:cocoa] and not [tag:cocoa-touch] in my feed reader). However, I think people will continue to tag questions as [tag:cocoa] (not looking at/ignoring/overriding the completions). If you make that a synonym, you're back to the same problem, as people will still tag their questions [tag:cocoa] and then they'll be tagged as [tag:cocoa-osx].

Comment: @PaddedCell: The problem isn't how best to tag Cocoa questions; the problem is people mistagging their Cocoa Touch questions as [tag:cocoa].

Comment: -1 I don't think this is a big deal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My money is on sticking with [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) for Mac-related questions.  As you state, Apple clearly indicates that Cocoa refers to the traditional frameworks used for developing Mac applications, while Cocoa Touch is the mobile variety.  I don't think that adding an -osx at the end of the tag helps, because there really isn't anything to disambiguate here.

Also, the tag summary has a very clear indication of what belongs in that tag:

> Cocoa is Apple's application-development framework for Mac OS X,
>   consisting of Foundation, Application Kit (AppKit), and Core Data. For
>   iOS (iPhone/iPad), see [cocoa-touch].

I've found that people who care about tagging things properly do follow the instructions of the tag summary.  For example, after I edited the [arc](/questions/tagged/arc) summary to indicate that automatic reference counting questions belong in [automatic-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting), I saw a significant drop in ambiguously tagged ARC questions.

If someone's unwilling to follow the instructions of the tag summary, and just use Cocoa blindly, what's to stop them from doing so even after [cocoa-osx](/questions/tagged/cocoa-osx) is created?  [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) would just become a dumping ground for questions by people who don't know where to place things.

To be honest, while I do see this mis-tagging from time to time, given the volume of [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) and [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) questions it seems to be an infrequent occurrence.  I think retagging proper [cocoa] questions to [cocoa-osx] would make things less clear and less easy to search.  It would also disrupt the people who watch [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) for questions.  I have no problem in just retagging them as I find them, and steering people in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I guess Peter and you are right: people who don’t care about proper tagging would still use the cocoa tag.